# Excel Defined Name List in Index dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have cells that list the following

```
   **MyList**
1             green
2             blue
3             red
4             yellow
5             special
6             special
```

And I have a Specials list defined as special

```
   **Special**
apple
banana
grapes
```

I have the a formula that looks for a match and displays its value in a drop down so if 2 is listed in the left-most column blue would be the only drop down selection.

```
=INDEX($A$15:$B$20,MATCH($E20,$A$15:$A$20,0),2)
```

But the drop down for cells with 5 and 6 say 'special' it does not drop down the defined list name(special) contents.

How can I include a defined name in this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your lookup table to more closely represent the following:

[image]

Base the F20 Data Validation List's Source: on the following formula,

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($B$15:$B$20, MATCH(E20, $A$15:$A$20, 0)), 0, 0, 1, MATCH("zzz", INDEX($B$15:$D$20, MATCH(E20, $A$15:$A$20, 0), 0)))
```

The dynamic list in F20 should follow the table lookup from the value in E20.

[image]

If you are running out of room (C19:D20) then you may have to relocate the list altogether.

Comment: What does the "zzz" represent?

Comment: Never mind figured it out its the named list from A15:A20.

Comment: No, that's not it. If you look for **zzz** with the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) using the default **1** as the *match_type* then it will return the position of the last text value in a range. In the above sample image, it will return 1 for B15:D15, B16:D16, B17:D17 and B18:D18. It returns **3** for B19:D19 and B20:D20. This is the width of the range to include in hte data validation list.